# How to do a case-insensitive search?

Tags: r

I was using `grep` to do a case-insensitive search, but the problem is I get all values containg the pattern, not just the exact match, but if I use `fixed=TRUE` that invalidates the `ignore.case=TRUE` parameter.

```
g = c("PLD3","PLD2","PLD2ABC","DTPLD2a")
r = "pLd2"
grep(r,g,ignore.case=TRUE,value=TRUE)
>[1] "PLD2"    "PLD2ABC" "DTPLD2a"

grep(r,g,ignore.case=TRUE,value=TRUE,fixed=TRUE)
>character(0)
```

**EDIT**

`r` is a user input, so basically it can be anything from a list of 30,000 genes, and it can be all lower-case, all upper-case, or a mixture of both. 
And also in my list `g` the elements can be upper-case, lower-case or a mixture (it is a list of around 15,000 genes)

Comment: Maybe just convert both to lower case and check if it's equal? `g[tolower(g)==tolower(r)]`.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
g = c("PLD3","PLD2","PLD2ABC","DTPLD2a")
r <- 'pLd2'
r2 <- paste('^', r, '$', sep = '')
grep(r2 , g ,ignore.case = T, value=TRUE)

[1] "PLD2"
```

basically the meta characters `^` and `$` force grep to fix the regular expression at the start and the end.

Comment: thank you, I am sorry, I didn't specify, that `r` is a user input, so basically it can be anything. I will update the post with this info